# How do can I access variable that is declared in a function?

Tags: python, function, variables, python-3.6

I have the following code:

**Script1**

```
def encoder(input_file):
    # a bunch of other code
    # some more code

    # path to output of above code
    conv_output_file = os.path.join(input_file_gs, output_format)
    subprocess.run(a terminal file conversion runs here)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    encoder("path/to/file")
```

And this is how I try to import and how I set it in script2.

**Script2**

```
from script1 import encoder
# some more code and imports
# more code 
# Here is where I use the output_location variable to set the input_file variable in script 2
input_file = encoder.conv_output_file
```

What I am trying to do is use variable output_location in another python3 file. So I can tell script2 where to look for the file that it is trying to process without hardcoding it in.

Every time I run the script though I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'conv_output_file' is not defined
```

Comment: Why can't you just `return conv_output_file` in your function?

Comment: what is the problem/error in each of these approaches? add more code of what you have tried so far

Comment: @idjaw I have tried this, but I still get keep getting `conv_output_file is not defined error.`

Comment: @EliC Then you are not doing something right in how you are importing and running that code. You need to show a better [mcve] of your problem to help readers understand better what problem you are facing.

Comment: @idjaw I figured out part of the issue. I am using `subprocess.run()` to run a terminal command and I was declaring the variable after this because I thought it was needed there, turns out it was. After moving that up I now see in my debugging step process that it is set to the correct string value but for some reason the import is unsuccessful. I have updated the question with more information above.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson 

Answer (score -1):

What I get from your description is that you want to get a local variable from another python file.

Return it or make it a global variable, and import it.

---

Maybe you have some difficulty in importing it correctly.

Make these two points clear:

1. you could only import packages in two ways: the package in PYTHONPATH or the local package. Especially, if you want do any relative import, add `.` before your package name to specify the package you want to import.
2. Python interpreter treat a directory as a package only if there is a `__init__.py` under the directory.

Answer (score -1):

what you actually want to do with the variable conv_output_file? if you just want to get the value/object to which conv_output_file binds, then you better use return statement. or if you want to access the variable and do some more thing on that variable i.e modifying it then you can use global to access the variable conv_output_file.

```
def encoder(input_file):
    # a bunch of other code
    # some more code

    # path to output of above code
    global conv_output_file
    conv_output_file = os.path.join(input_file_gs, output_format)
```

you can access the variable now from 2nd script as firstscript.conv_output_file only after calling that function firstscript.encoder(...) because until the function is not invoked variable does not eists . but it is not recommended to use global, you should avoid the use of global.

I think you want to get that value not access variable so better use return statement
def encoder(input_file):
        # a bunch of other code
        # some more code

```
    # path to output of above code
    return conv_output_file
    conv_output_file = os.path.join(input_file_gs, output_format)
    return conv_output_file
```

or simply

```
     return os.path.join(input_file_gs, output_format)
```

Answer (score -2):

I think apart from not returning the variable or not declaring it as a class variable, you're probably making another mistake.

> tell that 2nd script

You have to properly `import` the 1st script into your second script and use the `encoder` function as an attribute of the 1st script.

For example, name your first script `encoder_script`.
In second script,

```
import encoder_script
encoder_script.encode(filename)
```